# Misunderstanding With If and Else

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and would like some help!

I am working on some code that allows the user to find out if specific cows on his farm aren't producing enough milk.

On line 75 the if statement is supposed to print out the cows that 'are not good enough' or Tell the user that everything is OK. But instead it permanently try's to print the Bad Cows.

```
Console.WriteLine("How many cows are in your herd?");
int CowNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int Temp;
double TempD;
string TempS;
int MinimumVal = 6;
int MDIR = 4;

string[] BadList = new string[CowNum];
int[] Counter = new int[CowNum];
double[] Total = new double[CowNum];
string[] Days = new string[7] {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
string[] CowID = new string[CowNum];
double[,] CowYield = new double[CowNum, 7];


Random r = new Random();

for (int n = 0; n < CowNum; n++) // Sets Cow ID's
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is the ID of Cow: " + (n + 1) + "?" );
    TempS = (Console.ReadLine());
    CowID[n] = TempS;
}

for (int n = 0; n < CowNum; n++) // Sets the Yield of each cow to a certin day
    for (int x = 0; x < Days.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What was the Yeild for Cow: " + CowID[n] + " on " + Days[x] + "?");
        TempD = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        CowYield[n, x] = TempD;
        if (TempD < MinimumVal)
        {
            Counter[n] = Counter[n] + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(Counter[n]);
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("What was the Yeild for Cow: " + CowID[n] + " on " + Days[x] + "?"); //Randomly Generated 'Saves Time'
        //Temp = r.Next(0, 20);
        //Console.WriteLine(Temp);
        //CowYield[n, x] = Temp;
    }

for (int n = 0; n < CowNum; n++)
    for (int x = 0; x < Days.GetLength(0); x++)
        Total[n] = Total[n] + CowYield[n, x];

for (int n = 0; n < CowNum; n++)
{
    if (Counter[n] > MDIR)
    {
        BadList[n] = CowID[n];
        Console.WriteLine("asd" + BadList[n]);
    }
}


        int index = Array.IndexOf(Total, Total.Max()); // Gets index of Highest producing cow
TempS = CowID[index];
Console.WriteLine("\nThe Highest producing cow is Cow: " + TempS + ". with a whopping " + Total[index] + "L of Milk!\n");

if (BadList.GetLength(0) > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(BadList.GetLength(0));
    for (int n = 0; n < BadList.GetLength(0); n++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(BadList[n]);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("None of your cows had less than 6L of milk for four or more days in a row!");
}



Console.ReadLine();
```

}

Comment: Because you defined badlist as an array of cows of x value..  If you want a variable length you can add cows to, make it a list.

Comment: I wonder which of the hundreds of lines is number 75 on your screen...

Comment: I'm skeptic even without reading your question, `if/else` is not a yesterday thing, it was working for decades and will work for many years, so the problem is in your code (or maybe the not expected result). Also please try be more specified about your problem.

Comment: @BugFinder  What do you mean?

Comment: See my answer - you CAN still use an array however, you would need to take the number of populated answers not the length of the array..

Comment: @KaiHarris - it's in his answer. Basically you are creating a fixed length array `BadList` of length `CowNum` as input by the user and then checking the length of `BadList`, which is always > 0.

Comment: @spodger Yeah, it was a pretty obvious mistake... My bad  :/

Answer (score 0):

In short your code fails beause
(For ease of all of us, heres a simplified one)

```
string[] thing = new string[200]
if (thing.Length>0)
{  Console.WriteLine("All wrong");}
else
{  Console.WriteLine("OK");}
```

Your Length of thing is always 200 because you made it that big. So output is always "All wrong"

However if you had

```
List<String> thing = new List<String>();
//process list here, and use thing.Add(badcow)
if (thing.Count() >0 )
{  Console.WriteLine("All wrong");}
else
{  Console.WriteLine("OK");}
```

then it will work because there maybe 0 entries in the list. It may produce both answers and will pick as you expected.